# YII2 The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Totally new to the framework (YII2) and my first interaction with the framework am working with an already existing web app done was developed by someone else. After successful connection to the database, I try visiting the site through localhost just to get an error ***The requested URL /dwg/auth/auth/login was not found on this server.***

I get this on both windows machine and linux. What could be the issue? Have I missed something on the configuration?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName www.dwg.com
        ServerAlias www.dwg.com
        DocumentRoot /home/hemedi/public_html

        <Directory /home/hemedi/public_html/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What web server are you using? Could you expand the question by showing the configuration of your virtual host?

Comment: I am using Apache2

Comment: added the virtual host in the original question @Ale please check

Comment: Check out this link https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md#recommended-apache-configuration-

Comment: great. Thanks @Ale

Answer (score 0):

its now working. DId move all the project files to the root directory /var/www/html `mv dwg/* /var/www/html`